# Sorted is not working in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I used sorted method in Swift in Xcode 6.3 as

```
sorted(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName) as! [String])
```

I downloaded Xcode 7 beta, it says "sorted in unavailable, call sort on the collection". Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many free functions in swift 1.2 now moved into protocol extensions

```
(UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(familyName) as! [String]).sortInPlace()
```

In swift book protocol extensions explained like this

> Protocols can be extended to provide method and property
>   implementations to conforming types. This allows you to define
>   behavior on protocols themselves, rather than in each type’s
>   individual conformance or in a global function.

Comment: or in a simpler case var testArr = arrived.sort()